# How to allow an SCP client to change file mod time without being the owner

Tags: file-permissions, scp, winscp

WinSCP complains at me when it tries to change the file modification time of a file it doesn't own.  It says, **set times: Operation not permitted**.  I can remove this error message by unchecking "Preserve timestamp" in WinSCP settings (as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32482812/650004 ).  But I want to keep this setting on.  I want to configure SSHD (I think) on my server to allow setting the file modification time to anyone with write access to the file.

I looked in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and I can't see anything that might do it.

How can I do this?

Comment: You may want to read up on ACL.

Answer (score 1):

It's how Linux permissions works.

No settings in SSH server can override that.

In other words your question is about Linux system, not about sshd, SCP, let alone WinSCP.